# Onchange didn't work on dynamically added row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I am new to jquery and in this project, I am trying to make pharmacy system. I want a function where a user can add purchases from a supplier.
Here is my code:

```
 $(document).on('change', '.supplier_name', function() {

         var supplier_name = $('.supplier_name').val();

        $.ajax({
            url : "<?php echo base_url('example/getmedbysupplier')?>",
            method : "POST",
            data : {supplier_name: supplier_name},
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var html = '';
                var i;
                html += '<option selected="true" value="" disabled >Choose medicine</option>';
                for(i=1; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<option>'+data[i].medicine_name+'</option>';
                }
                $('.medicine_name').html(html);

            }
        });
        });


var count = 1;

      $('#addpurchase').on( 'click', function () {
        purchase.row.add( [
          '<select style="width:100%;" class="form-control medicine_name" id="medicine_name'+count+'" name="medicine_name[]" data-stock="#stock'+count+'" data-unit="#unit'+count+'" data-price="#price'+count+'"><option selected="true" value="" disabled >Choose supplier</option>',
          '<input id="stock'+count+'" name="stock[]" class="form-control stock" readonly >',
          '<input id="unit'+count+'" name="unit[]" class="form-control" readonly>',
          '<input id="price'+count+'" name="price[]" class="form-control price" readonly>',
          '<input type="number" id="quantity'+count+'" name="quantity[]" class="form-control quantity">',
          '<input id="subtotal'+count+'" name="subtotal[]" class="form-control subtotal" readonly>',
          '<button id="removeproduct" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete</button>',
        ] ).draw( false );

        count++;

      } );
```

The problem is the onchange only works one. When I add the row again, it keep telling me to choose supplier (which I've already done). I've tried another solution like bind jquery, parent/sibling, and others but it only works inside the table.

[image]

So I figured it out by click buttons as many as I want, then after that I choose the supplier, like this:
[image]

How to make it work automatically onchange (that I don't need to add the product first)?

Comment: It seems that when onchange happens you want the ajax response to be added to the `.medicine_name` element corresponding with the selected `.supplier_name` entry.  But this line `$(".medicine_name").html(html)` will add the response to the *first* `.medicine_name` element on the page.  That’s why it works the first time.

Comment: Yeah, the onchange only respond to what appear in that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Your function bound to `#addpurchase` is generating something is not true. It is creating a select element without closing tag and with only a choose supplier option.

```
<select style="width:100%;" class="form-control medicine_name" id="medicine_name'+count+'" name="medicine_name[]" data-stock="#stock'+count+'" data-unit="#unit'+count+'" data-price="#price'+count+'"><option selected="true" value="" disabled >Choose supplier</option>
```

So how do you expect a new row without choose suppplier text in it?

Comment: My bad, I forgot the closing tag. Now after I add it, the problem still exists

Comment: Did you add the other options into the select element or there still only Choose Supplier option? @RiaW

Comment: No, I didn't add the other options

Comment: Your select element should be incliding the products as option inside.